# NumPy structured / regular array from ctypes pointer to array of structs

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

Say I have the following `C` function:

```
void getArrOfStructs(SomeStruct** ptr, int* numElements)
```

And the following `C` struct:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I am able to successfully get a Python list:

```
class SomeStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_int),
                ('y', c_int)]
ptr, numElements = pointer(SomeStruct()), c_int()
myDLL.getArrOfStructs(byref(ptr), byref(numElements)))
```

I want to get a NumPy structured / regular array.

1. Structured vs Regular array: which one is preferable (in terms of terminology)?
2. How can I do it? I'm looking for an efficient way (without copy each cell). I tried NumPy's `frombuffer()` functions, but was only able to use it with regular `C` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views of numpy arrays share a data buffer

```
In [267]: x=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
In [268]: x.tostring()
Out[268]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00'
In [269]: x.view('i,i')
Out[269]: 
array([[(0, 1)],
       [(2, 3)],
       [(4, 5)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

In this example the databuffer is a C array of 24 bytes, which can viewed in various ways - a flat array, 2 columns, or structured array with 2 fields.

I haven't worked with `ctypes` but I'm sure there's something equivalent to `np.frombuffer` to construct an array from a byte buffer.

```
In [273]: np.frombuffer(x.tostring(),int)
Out[273]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [274]: np.frombuffer(x.tostring(),'i,i')
Out[274]: 
array([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Thanks, chaging the `dtype` did the job.